# Unable to scroll to last comment in my app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am not able to scroll to last comment using this code:

```
var item = viewModel.ListPostComments.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CommentID.Equals(comment));

if (item != null) 
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => DetailAndCommentsListView.ScrollTo(item, ScrollToPosition.Center, true));
}
```

I want the app to automatically scroll to the most recently added comment. How can I fix that?

Comment: what's the problem? do you get any exception? it "item" null or the comment is found?

Comment: Nothing. It is not scrolling and neither doing anything else.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line after "var item =" and check the value of item, what is it?

Comment: The breakpoint did not reached this place. I am looking into it again. I will post back once I figure out right flow

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The flow was not correct I moved it to right position and now its working but I have one small problem. I only want to scroll to bottom when new comment is added , right now its scrolling to bottom every time I open a post. How do I deal with that_

Comment: Just move this code to the place where you add new comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(new_comment_check == true)  // If new comment added then scroll to it 
            {
                var item = viewModel.ListPostComments.LastOrDefault();
                if (item != null) Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => DetailAndCommentsListView.ScrollTo(item, ScrollToPosition.End, true));
            }
```

This is the correct code. It worked